# Closed form for generating function of Riemann Xi function

Tags: special-functions, generating-functions, closed-form, riemann-zeta

What is the closed form for

$$f(x)=\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\xi(k)x^k}{k!}$$

or

$$g(x)=\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\xi(k+1/2)x^k}{k!}$$

or

$$w(x)=\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\xi(k+1/2)x^k}{(k^2-1/4)k!}$$

?

Comment: what is the definition of $\xi(k)$?

Comment: @mike it is Rieman Xi-function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function

Comment: The summation for $f(x)$ should start from $k=1$ because if $\xi(s)=(1/2)s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$, then $\Gamma(0)$ is not well defined.

Comment: @mike fixed, thanks (although I think using limit one can easily overcome the issue).

Comment: @Anixx Even starting at k=1 you would need a limit because ζ(1) is undefined as well.

Comment: @Nicholas Pipitone okay, this all is not important. One can take $\Gamma(0)=\gamma$ and $\zeta(1)=-\gamma$.